# Calculation error in python when doing the calculation at different points in my code

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following issue that I cannot solve: Using two variables that I update in a for-loop, the value I compute by subtracting one from the other is different when I do the calculation at different points in my code, even though the two variables do not change in between.

In particular, I am calculating a value `co[t] = max([0, est[t][ch] - est[t][sug] + eps])`, once before I set values for `est[t+1]` and once after. Below is a sample output where the problem can be seen:

```
494: Accepted
494: co[t] pre = 2.11863208054
494: co[t] post = 1.69490566443
494: est[t][ch] = 2.49012790412
494: est[t][sug[t]] = 0.805222239686
```

Clearly, the value `co[t] post` is correct, while `co[t] pre` is incorrect. Below is the code used to produce this output:

```
sug = [0 for i in time]
co = [0 for i in time]
est = [[0 for i in op] for j in time]

eps = 0.01
alph = 0.2

for t in time:
    ch = random.choice(op)
    sug[t] = random.choice(op)
    co[t] = max([0, est[t][ch] - est[t][sug[t]] + eps])
    if t < T-1:
        est[t+1] = est[t]
        if ac[ch] >= ac[sug[t]] + co[t]:
            print '%s: Declined' % t
            est[t+1][ch] += alph*co[t]
        elif ac[ch] < ac[sug[t]] + co[t]:
            print '%s Accepted' % t
            est[t+1][ch] -= alph*co[t]
    else:
            break

    print '%s: co[t] pre = %s' % (t, co[t])
    print '%s: co[t] post = %s' % (t, max([0, est[t][ch] - est[t][sug[t]] + eps]))
    print '%s: est[t][ch] = %s' % (t, est[t][ch])
    print '%s: est[t][sug[t]] = %s' % (t, est[t][sug[t]])
```

As can be seen, `co[t] pre` is computed BEFORE the `if t < T-1`-clause, while `co[t] post` is computed AFTER. Note that neither `est[t][ch]` nor `est[t][sug]` are changed within the if-clause.

I cannot explain why this is happening!

I apologize if this question has been asked before. Upon searching it I only found issues where large floating point numbers caused problems, but I don't think this is relevant here since I am using the exact same variables (`est[t][ch]` and `est[t][sug]`) both times I compute `co[t]`.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: Apologies, the missing part of the code is:

```
import random

op = [i for i in range(4)]
ac = [3, 2, 1, 0]

T = 500
time = range(T)
```

Comment: What is the value of `time` and `op` in the code?

Comment: ...and `T`.....

Comment: time is set as `time = range(T)`, where `T = 500`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, not knowing exactly what this code is supposed to do, but the mostly likely culprit is:

```
est[t+1] = est[t]
```

You're probably intending that to send a *copy* of `est[t]` forward, but what you are in fact doing is making all of the sublists in `est` references to *the same* list. So when you change values in `est[t]`, you're also changing them in `est[t-1]`, `est[t-2]`, etc. To see this in action, after you run your code, print `est` and compare the sublists.

Try this, and see if it does what you're expecting:

```
est[t+1] = list(est[t])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you are writing:

```
est[t+1] = est[t]
```

Then you are actually assigning the reference of `est[t]` in `est[t+1]`. So any change in `est[t+1]` is also reflected in `est[t]`. If you want to copy contents of a list, instead of assigning reference, you can typecast it again as `list()` like this:

```
est[t+1] = list(est[t])
```

`list()` function returns a new list and does not modify whatever is passed to it as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed the mistake! Also, thanks for the explanation, coming from Matlab this is new to me.